# ServiceStack OrmLite Sql Query Logging

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

As per the [Service Stack Ormlite documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite). I should generate the sql query in debug mode. But, I am not able to see those queries.  Simple code

```
 private static readonly string DataDirLoc =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +
        "\\TargetIntegration\\Test\\Debug\\";



    private readonly string dbFileName = DataDirLoc +
                                              "Test.db3";

    [Test]
    public void Can_Generate_log() {
        //var writer = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
        //Debug.Listeners.Add(writer);
        Debug.Write("this is a try");
        var dbFact = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source={0};Version=3;".FormatParams(dbFileName), true,
                                                  SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
          IDbConnection dbConnection = dbFact.OpenDbConnection();
       var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
        dbCommand.CreateTable<Contact>();
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need the debug build of OrmLite to see the SQL output.
There are a couple of other ways you can view the last sql:

```
Console.WriteLine(dbCmd.GetLastSql());
```

You can also profile the db connection by setting a connection filter, which you can do with:

```
var dbFact = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
   "Data Source={0};Version=3;".Fmt(dbFileName), true, 
   SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance) {
   ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
};
```

Which if you ran this in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) will let you see the profiled timing outputs of all the SQL statements. An example of what this looks like is available here:

https://gist.github.com/1787443

Comment: thanks Demis. But, I am using ORMlite in a windows application. I dont think I can use MVC mini profiler. May be I am wrong. Please guide.

Comment: and by default there is no extension method "GetLastSql()" on dbCommand I can use "CommandText". But it only gives the last executed statement.

Comment: Well if you hosted a ServiceStack self-hosted HttpListener service you could :) but a webserver in a WinApp seems a bit heavy for debugging. You could also create your own ProfiledDbConnection and just have it log all SQL to the console. Here's the src https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/MiniProfiler/Data/ProfiledDbConnection.cs

Comment: Update NuGet, if you don't have `dbCmd.GetLastSql()` but its just a wrapper around dbCmd.CommandText, so won't help if you want more than that :)

Comment: Great Suggestions :).. I guess will create my own "ProfiledDbConnection " Thanks anyways .. great help